# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me sale esta advertencia al momento de ingresar datos en un formulario, la base de datos la lee pero creo que hay un problema cuando se insertan en la tabla.

¿A que se deberá este problema? No lo puedo encontrar, reviso y reviso y no encuentro nada :(

Un dato que agregar, que al momento de ingresar los datos de la tabla, no puse id ya que es auto increment.

conex.php

```
$conectar=mysqli_connect('localhost','protectk_root','auxilio12345');
if (!$conectar) {
    echo "No se pudo conectar con el servidor";
}else{
    $base=mysqli_select_db('protectk_protectKids');
    if(!$base){
        echo "No se encontro la base de datos";
    }
}

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$curso=$_POST['curso'];
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$tipo=$_POST['motivo'];
$descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];

$sql=($conectar, "INSERT INTO denuncias VALUES ('$nombre','$curso','$fecha','$motivo','$descripcion')");

$ejecutar=mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);

if (!$ejecutar) {
    echo "Hubo algun error";
}else{
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='Bienvenido.php'>Volver</a>";
}



?>
```

Comment: @Marcos el problema es otro, osea la advertencia es igual lógicamente, pero el problema deriva de otra causa.

Comment: @Aprendizel problema es otro, osea la advertencia es igual lógicamente, pero el problema deriva de otra causa.

Comment: @Aprendiz porque los codigos son diferentes

Comment: @Aprendiz elimine los @ y pase la variable conectar al ejecutar, y aun así sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: @Aprendiz el error sigue siendo el mismo, pero hice lo que me dijiste y persiste

Comment: @Aprendiz modificado!

Comment: @nicolasyo1WWE Este error podría deberse a una comilla en la cadena. Por favor, agrega los valores que estás pasando en el formulario. Además, ten en cuenta que la generación de sentencias SQL concatenando cadenas es insegura por naturaleza y hace que tu código se vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas en su lugar.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro efectivamente es una coma, pero no se donde ponerla, miro y miro y no se donde colocarla

Comment: @Aprendiz sabes?

Comment: Yo noto rara esta línea `$sql=($conectar, "INSERT INTO denuncias VALUES ('$nombre','$curso','$fecha','$motivo','$descripcion')");` por que se supone que en la función `mysqli_query()` ya estas pasando la variable `$conectar`, entonces lo que yo propongo es: **quita la variable $conectar de la sentencia `INSERT`** y prueba de nuevo

Comment: @Aprendiz Nuevamente salio el error anterior (mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in), no se encuentra la BD

Comment: no uses `mysqli_select_db`, pasa los 4 parámetros `localhost, user, database, pass` al método `mysqli_connect("localhost", "protectk_root", "auxilio12345", "protectk_protectKids");` y comenta la línea que tiene esto `//$base=mysqli_select_db('protectk_protectKids');`

Comment: @nicolasyo1WWE lo que Aprendiz te está sugiriendo es quitar la variable `$conectar` en esta línea: `$sql=($conectar, "INSERT...`, pero por lo que comentas la estás quitando en esta otra línea `$ejecutar=mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);`

Comment: se complicó la recomendación en los comentarios, por eso opté por colocarlo como respuesta

Comment: @nicolasyo1WWE en tu tabla `denuncias` hay un campo llamado `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Atendiendo a la observación que te hizo el mod. Alvaro te recomiendo esta lectura: [Sentencias preparadas](https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), además te recomiendo leer esta [respuesta de Álvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/18233#18233) al respecto del tema

Por otro lado tu código debería ser este:

```
<?php 
$conectar=mysqli_connect('localhost','protectk_root','auxilio12345', 'protectk_protectKids');
if (!$conectar) {
    echo "No se pudo conectar con el servidor";
}else{
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $curso=$_POST['curso'];
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
    $tipo=$_POST['motivo'];
    $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];

    $sql= "INSERT INTO denuncias VALUES ('".$nombre."','".$curso."','".$fecha."','".$motivo."',
                                         '".$descripcion."')";

    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);

    if (!$ejecutar) {
        echo "Hubo algun error";
    }else{
        echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='Bienvenido.php'>Volver</a>";
    }

}

?>
```

- Usamos `mysqli_connect()` para pasarle los 4 parámetros de acceso:

  - localhost
  - user
  - contarseña
  - database
- Eliminamos el uso de `mysqli_select_db()`
- En la variable `$sql` solo almacenamos la query
- Concatenamos las variables dentro de la query de este modo: `'".$variable."'`
- Dejamos que `mysqli_query()` reciba la variable de conexion y la variable que almacena la query

Comment: Me sale el mensaje: "Hubo un error", sera donde no esta declarada la variable id?

Comment: ¿cuál variable `$id`? @nicolasyo1WWE

Comment: Exactamente, lo dudo si ya que es auto incremente, pero tampoco es descartable

Comment: umm se me agotan las opciones. lo único que ahorita se me ocurre es que agregues en la sentencia SQL los nombres de las columnas igual no incluyas la del `id`

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo pondría así la parte del SQL:

```
   $sql= 'INSERT INTO `denuncias` (`nombre`,`curso`,`fecha`,`motivo`,`descripcion`)  VALUES ("'.$nombre.'","'.$curso.'","'.$fecha.'","'.$motivo.'","'.$descripcion.'")';
```

Suponiendo que los nombres en la BD sean iguales que los nombres de las variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yo quitaría la función `mysqli_select_db()` y pondría el nombre de tu base de datos directamente en el conectar:

```
$conectar = mysqli_connect('localhost','protectk_root','auxilio12345', 'protectk_protectKids');
```

Después en tu `query` si mencionas que tu `id` es `AUTO_INCREMENT` en tu `BD`, debes indicarlo en tu `INSERT INTO` con `DEFAULT`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO denuncias VALUES (DEFAULT,'$nombre','$curso','$fecha','$motivo','$descripcion'");
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
<?php 

    $conectar = mysqli_connect('localhost','protectk_root','auxilio12345', 'protectk_protectKids');

    if (!$conectar) {
        echo "No se pudo conectar con el servidor";
    }else{
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $curso = $_POST['curso'];
        $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
        $tipo = $_POST['motivo'];
        $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO denuncias VALUES (DEFAULT,'$nombre','$curso','$fecha','$motivo','$descripcion'");


        $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);

        if (!$ejecutar) {
            echo "Hubo algun error";
        }else{
            echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='Bienvenido.php'>Volver</a>";
        }
    }
?>
```